# Tracking schedule after setting baseline

Tags: ms-project

In MS Project after setting a baseline, how do you show that a task is now estimated to take less time than originally thought?

For example the original estimated duration was 10 days, this was set as the baseline, but we now know that the task will only take 5 days.

Comment: I think that is the variance - Project has a column for variance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use the Insert Column function to show "Baseline Finish" and "Baseline Duration" in your schedule. Then manipulate the value in the "Duration" column to show that the task will only take 5 days. You can now compare "Finish" with "Baseline Finish" to see the net effect on your schedule.

Comment: aha this works thank you!  I had previously been modifying the "scheduled finish" column to reflect changes to esimated completion dates.  But that approach would not allow me to put in a scheduled completion date before the baseline finish date.

Comment: Also, considering using "remaining duration" to update what you expect to use.  It has the same effect.